# Web Service multi-client basic question

Tags: service

I've been reading up on web service all day but I'm still missing a basic understanding on web services as they relate to multiple clients.

The web service runs on a web server.  The service exposes various methods.  Multiple clients may call the same service method simultaneously.  Question: Does each client get its own copy of the method or does the code in the method implementation have to start a thread for each client and process each client's request in it's own thread?  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

- DP

Comment: I think this is a programming language specific question. Can you tell us which programming languages you are considering?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on configuration. In WCF you can configure 'singleton' ie. one service instance, which will work with all clients. Or you can set another value which will create separate instance for each client calling it. You will definitely get more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Edit:

Check this attribute: [**InstanceContextBehavior**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. That was the pointer I was looking for. So, with the Singleton, you do all of the multi-client handling yourself in the web-service method.  In the per-call (and maybe per-session) modality, there is a separate instance of the service for each client.  I assume the singleton would be the most efficient with the least overhead and the others will be easier to code and less efficent.  The best way to go depends on expected usage I guess.